# Immutable type and property in C#

Tags: c#, types, immutability

What is meant by immutable type and immutable property in C# ? can you give simple example?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An immutable type is a type of which its properties can only be set at initialization. Once an object is created, nothing can be changed anymore. An immutable property is simply a read-only property.

In the following example, `ImmutableType` is an immutable type with one property `Test`. Test is a read-only property. It can only be set at construction.

```
class ImmutableType
{
    private readonly string _test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
    }

    public ImmutableType(string test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }
}
```

**See also**: [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), and [some Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable) [Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352471/how-do-i-create-an-immutable-class) on the topic.

Comment: You can enforce immutability against future class changes by prefixing _test with readonly.  Alas, sadly there are no immutable auto-implemented properties in C#.

Comment: This gets a bit trickier when your properties are reference types.  The definition, then, of immutable can be interpreted as the *reference* is immutable _or_ the *object graph* is immutable (depending on your needs, but typically it's the latter - see the Wiki article).

Comment: With reference types, it means you can only instantiate it and assign to it once. For example, I can have a "readonly" List, but I can add to and remove from that list all I want to.

Comment: Note: Sam's comment is nolonger true. Starting with C# 6 you can have immutable auto-implmented properties using just `{ get; }`

Comment: Can one drop the public in front of string Test? I guess so.

Comment: c#9 has some extended ways to make things immutable : [init-only-setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#init-only-setters) [record-types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @fretje's answer above, in C#6 and later, [getter-only auto properties](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#getter-only-auto-properties) have now been implemented, which allows for immutable auto-properties without the need for the additional explicit `private readonly` backing field. The equivalent code would be abbreviated to:

```
class ImmutableType
{
    public string Test
    {
        get; // No Set at all, not even a private set.
    }

    public ImmutableType(string test)
    {
        Test = test; // The compiler understands this and initializes the backing field
    }
}
```

Note that `private set` only provides a restricted encapsulation of change to the property from within the same class, and thus isn't truly immutable:

```
public string Test
{
    get;
    private set;  // Not immutable, since this is still mutable from within the class
}
```

**More about immutability**

As others have said, an `immutable Property` is a property which cannot change once it has been set. Setting of the 'only' value is done during construction.

An `immutable Type` is a type where all (externally visible) properties and fields are immutable - for example the "Record" Type originally scheduled for C#7 [(hopefully now 8)](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/milestone/8) would have been an immutable type. Other examples of Immutable Types are [`Tuples`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3131400/314291), and all [anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089406/why-are-the-properties-of-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp-read-only).

Immutable fields should be qualified with the `readonly` keyword in C# - this is enforced by the compiler to ensure that no other code attempts to change the field outside of the constructor.

Wherever possible, immutability of fields, variables and properties is regarded as good practice, as this greatly reduces the surface area for bugs (since fields represent the state of an object, preventing change to fields reduces the number of states).

The benefit of immutability is especially important in multi-threaded programs, where two or more threads concurrently access the same object. Since multiple concurrent reading threads can safely read the value of a field or property, the programmer doesn't need to be concerned about thread safety issues relating to change to the field by other threads (because change to the property is prohibited)

One common drawback of immutability when dealing with complex objects consisting of multiple composed objects, is that the entire graph needs to be built 'in one go', which can lead to messy code. A common solution here is to use the [Builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/696027/314291) as a scaffold, which allows a transient, mutable representation to be built in steps, and then the final, immutable object is obtained in the final `.Build()` step.

Answer (score 3):

fretje is correct. The most popular example of an immutable type is a `string` object in C#. This is the entire reason that `StringBuilder` exists.

Answer (score -1):

There is no clear definition for immutability in C#:

- It usually entails all public fields to be readonly and all public properties to have init setter or no setter.
- It may also extend this to private members (although it is common to use mutable private members to cache values ie the hashcode)
- It may also mean all members are themselves of immutable types. As otherwise a consumer can still modify the object by calling a member method
- It may also mean all methods always return the same output when called with the same arguments. In particular an immutable GetHashCode() means the object is safe to use as a key in dictionaries etc

A stronger and often more useful concept is that of - 'Data' an Immutable type which also has value semantics (usually by inheriting from `IEquatable<T>`)

Here is an example of a 'Data' type that satisfies all of the demands above:

```
record MyData(int age, DateTime JoinDate);
```

(see project [F](https://github.com/kofifus/F/wiki) for more on how Data types are useful)