# c# deleting class object with specific constructor properties from a list

Tags: c#

My question is: Is there any way that I can access constructor property after creating a new object.

I have created this class:

```
class Book
{
    private string Title { get; set; }
    private string Author { get; set; }
    private string ISBN { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }

    public Book(string title, string author, string isbn)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Author = author;
        this.ISBN = isbn;   
    }
}
```

Then I create a new object in a following way:

```
Book myBook = new Book("Strategic Management", "John Doe", "1234567");
```

How can I extract title from the object above? I need to use the Title in the following syntax:

```
    public void RemoveLoan(Book oldLoan)
    {

        var item = Loans.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Book.Title == oldLoan.Title);
        if (item != null)
        {
            Loans.Remove(item);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are those properties private? and no you can't access them since they are private.

Comment: Make the properties `public`.  You can always make them readonly like this `public string Title { get; private set; }`

Comment: This is a school assignment, I am just following the requirements.

Comment: Are you *certain* the requirements (which aren't stated in the question) include that all the properties are private. That seems very odd.

Comment: Thanks juharr, it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, only `setter` method is encapsulated in properties :

```
// setter is encapsulated, while getter is public allowing you to acess value
public string Title { get; private set; }
public string Author { get; private set; }
public string ISBN { get; private set; }
```

Alternatively you can use `readonly` fields to make your class [*immutable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537620/immutable-type-and-property-in-c-sharp) :

```
public readonly title;
public readonly author;
public readonly iSBN;
```